# Unity Constructor Injection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I am using Prism + Unity in a wpf application using MVVM.  I am a beginner with Prism and Unity.

I want to be able to close the current view.  The various solutions and articles I've read state that the best way to do this is from the view model.  But the view model needs a region manager object in order to close the view.  Ok, so let's set up constructor injection.  Never tried this before but there are plenty of questions on SO that deal with this.

Let me start with explaining how things are wired together.  I have a bootstrapper class that handles the registering of types and instances.

Here is how my view and view model is registered:

```
container.RegisterType<IViewModel, ViewAccountsViewModel>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(RegionManager))));
container.RegisterType<ViewAccountsView>();
```

Here is the module for the view accounts view:

```
public class ViewAccountsModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public ViewAccountsModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void Initialize()
    {
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", () => this.container.Resolve<ViewAccountsView>());
    }
}
```

In my ViewAccountsView.xaml, I am setting the data context like so:

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewAccountsViewModel/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

And my view model constructor:

```
[InjectionConstructor]
public ViewAccountsViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    if (regionManager == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("regionManager");

    this.regionManager = regionManager;
}
```

When I compile the solution, I receive an error that the type "ViewAccountsViewModel" does not include any accessible constructors.  If I add a default constructor to my view model, the view displays but I cannot remove the view from the region.  I get an argument null exception.

Here is the code for removing the view:

```
regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Remove(regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].GetView("ViewAccountsView"));
```

I am still very much a beginner with IoC and DI.  Is there something I have missed?

Comment: Add a default constructor and put break point on this constuctor. If this will work(stopping in the breakpoint) than something wrong with your registration(check all requried objects if they are all already registred).

Comment: I wanted to add that if I change to `container.RegisterType<IViewModel, ViewAccountsViewModel>();` my view displays but I can't remove the view.  My overloaded constructor does not get called.

Answer (score 5):

Unity will handle injecting all dependencies it knows about for you.  By default, Unity will call the constructor with the most parameters.  You usually use InjectionConstructor to either tell Unity to choose a different constructor when it creates the objects for you, or if you want to pass it custom parameters.

Registration:

```
container.RegisterType<IViewModel, ViewAccountsViewModel>();
// If you plan to have multiple IViewModels, it will need to have a name
// container.RegisterType<IViewModel, ViewAccountsViewModel>("ViewAccountsViewModelName");
container.RegisterType<ViewAccountsView>();
```

ViewModel:

```
// If you decide later you need other dependencies like IUnityContainer, you can just set 
// it in your constructor and Unity will give it to you automagically through the power 
// of Dependency Injection
// public ViewAccountsViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer unityContainer)
public ViewAccountsViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    this.regionManager = regionManager;
}
```

View Code Behind:

```
// If you have a named IViewModel
// public ViewAccountsView([Dependency("ViewAccountsViewModelName")]IViewModel viewModel)
public ViewAccountsView(IViewModel viewModel)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```